# Express middleware not firing when using postman but works when connecting with browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple express application boiler plated with Express Generator.

I am trying to run middleware to verify a JWT but none of my middleware seems to get run when testing with postman.

If I make a request from my browser, I can see the logs in the middleware run fine.

My app.js has a simple logger function which should run on all requests.

```
import token_verification from './middleware/token_verification';
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', api);

var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED')
  next()
}

app.use(myLogger)
app.use(token_verification);


const LOCALHOST = process.env.PORT || 3037;
app.listen(LOCALHOST, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${LOCALHOST}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I have my `routes/index.js` with a simple GET route

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

As I said, when I got to `http://localhost:3037/` in my browser, I can see my terminal logs "LOGGED" but when I make a GET request via post to the same URI, nothing is logged and appears no middleware runs.

EDIT:

Postman screenshot

[image: PostmanScreenshot]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot from postman?

Comment: @zb22 have added the screen shot. As you can see there are no headers set. Once again, no log was recorded from this request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it's working from the browser but not from Postman (there's likely some headers that *are* being set by the browser and not by postman, but I don't see why that would matter).

What does matter, though, is that you're defining your logger *after* your routes, and since your GET route ends the response with `res.render` the middleware will not fire.

Remember, in the latest versions of Express, middleware fires in the order they're mounted on the app.

If you want the logger to always fire, reorder things:

```
var myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED')
  next()
}

app.use(myLogger)
app.use(token_verification);
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/api', api);
```